# How can I suppress feedback when calling vim with certain commands?

Tags: command-line, invocation

I'm trying to automatically delete useless headers when calling `vim` from `mutt`. I've tried running `vim` with the following command.

```
vim +'0,/^$/g/^\(Cc\|Bcc\|Reply-To\): $/d' /tmp/test
```

However, I get the following feedback when it starts.

```
"/tmp/test" 11L, 60C
3 fewer lines
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

For testing purposes, if I remove the range and g (i.e. `0,/^$/g`), the command is as follows, and I do not get the additional prompt.

```
vim +'g/^\(Cc\|Bcc\|Reply-To\): $/d' /tmp/test
```

Why do I get the prompt for the first command? How can I suppress it?

### Edit

I seem to only get the prompt when the command deletes three lines, e.g. when `/tmp/test` consists of the following.

```
To: Foo
Cc: 
Bcc: 
Reply-To: 

foo
bar
```

However, when there are only two lines deleted, I get no prompt, e.g. when `/tmp/test` consists of the following.

```
To: Foo
Cc: Bar
Bcc: 
Reply-To: 

foo
bar
```

Comment: Try adjusting the `'cmdheight'` option before running the `global` command.

Comment: @VanLaser This works well. I do `set cmdheight=2` before the command, then `set cmdheight=1` after. I'd upvote if it were an answer.

Comment: I've also found references to both answers [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoiding_the_%22Hit_ENTER_to_continue%22_prompts).

Comment: It's ok :) the `silent` answer is actually better/shorter.

Comment: @VanLaser I actually quite like yours too, because it still notifies in case of error. `silent` (obviously) gives no indication if a command has failed.

Comment: Actually, `silent` doesn't mask errors.  Errors are only suppressed if you use `silent!`.

Comment: Perhaps "error" isn't the correct term. I meant the feedback that it had failed. (Having said that, this is what I asked for in the original question, so yours is the correct answer!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:silent` to suppress the output of the command.

```
vim +'silent 0,/^$/g/^\(Cc\|Bcc\|Reply-To\): $/d' /tmp/test
```

Comment: Thank you; works well (+1). However, do you have any idea why I get the prompt for this command (my first question)? And why only when it matches thrice?

Comment: @Sparhawk As already mentioned in comments to your question, when the output exceeds the value of 'cmdheight' it causes the hit-enter prompt. Vim does this to ensure you see ask the output. Since you don't care about the output, :silent is the right way to avoid the prompt.